# Stop default application per file type changing

Tags: finder

I'm now on High Sierra but have had this problem previously on El Capitan.

Sometimes, even directly after a reboot, files like .png or .jpg open, instead of in Preview, which is what I want, in some ancient canon photo util programs I still have on my system (which I should probably delete).

I'd like to know what could be happening here and to investigate - can anyone advise how to precisely control filetype associations and what are the common causes of this getting messed up?

Following other questions on this topic, if I do:

`cat  ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices.plist`

I just get:

`bplist00?`

Then if I view this file in vim, I get some unreadable characters. It turns out (after a quick search for bplist), that this is a binary format, so not editable in a text editor.  Is my only option to delete it?  Will it be regenerated?  Is there a way to view what all associations are currently and pinpoint all sources which may change them? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bplist is likely a "binary plist" file, which is why you see junk when you open that file in vim. Try opening the file with either something like [BBEdit](https://www.barebones.com/) or if you have the developer tools installed, there should be a command line program called plutil that you can use to convert to and from a binary plist.

Comment: plutil should be available even without developer tools installed. At least, it's available on my sans-developer-tools system.